# MySQL event executed two hours later than scheduled

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL event, defined as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT `My_Fancy_Event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2020-07-01 23:00:00.000'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO BEGIN    
    -- Do some fancy stuff 
END
```

(This was created at 2020-07-01 10:52:41.000 UTC)

However, when I looked in the database the next day, I saw this in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` table:
[image: EVENTS table]

It appears that even though my event was scheduled to execute at 2020-07-01 23:00:00.000, it actually occurred two hours later. This caused some problems, because we care about the current date in the event - it has to execute once per day.

Nothing I have found on the internet suggests that an event can be delayed by more than a few seconds. So, what's going on here?

**Edit**

This event has since successfully executed at the correct time:

[image: EVENTS table (three days later)]

I don't think it's anything to do with time zones, because that hasn't changed in the last three days. Also the event has its time zone specified as UTC, [which is the same](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-metadata.html) for both the `STARTS` and `LAST_EXECUTED` and columns in the table.

Comment: Just a guess but what about the timezone set on the server?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff thanks for the suggestion! I've made an update to the question.